# redirect_uri_mismatch while using HTTPS:// on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, google-api, google-oauth

Google signin works fine on my nodejs app via http (on Google App Engine).

But when tried via https - below error is received. Im using Google App Engine auto managed SSL.

> The redirect URI in the request,
>   http://www.example.com/api/auth/google/callback, does not match the
>   ones authorized for the OAuth client.

The problem seems to be - my nodejs app in google app engine does not know the traffic is coming from https - I am using express - how to resolve this ?

Paths in google cloud console for oauth to use http and https are correctly set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Developer console you set up some Redirect URIs to use with your client credentials.

You are currently trying to make a request and sending

> http://www.example.com/api/auth/google/callback

As your redirect uri that is has not been added as a valid one.  You either need to add as a valid one or better yet try sending from `https://www.example.com/api/auth/google/callback`  instead

My node.js knowledge is pretty basic but check your OAUTH2_CALLBACK

Comment: woooo.. I had only set redirect uri for http://example.com/api/auth/google/callback and not http://www.example.com/api/auth/google/callback - www was missing. I will try figure out to do it on https. Thank you.